# codeigniter cropping after watermarking

Tags: codeigniter

I have a little trouble here, I want upload my image with cropping and watermarking the image. Here's my controller code

```
//cropping image
$img['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
$img['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
$img['width'] = $thumb_size;
$img['height'] = $thumb_size;            
$this->image_lib->initialize($img);
$this->image_lib->crop();
$this->image_lib->clear();
$img['source_image'] = $source ;

//watermark image
$img['new_image']    = $destination_thumb ;
$img['wm_overlay_path'] = './images/resource/watermark.png';
$img['wm_type'] = 'overlay';
$img['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'midle';
$img['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'center';
$this->image_lib->initialize($img);
$this->image_lib->watermark();            
$this->image_lib->clear() ;
```

The all code is fine with no errors found, the code is only create watermark without cropping but when I reverse watermark code above of cropping code the result is only crop image.

So what I have to do that I can upload images with cropping and watermarking in one time?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

can you try this :

```
$img['source_image'] = $source ;

$img['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
$img['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
$img['width'] = $thumb_size;
$img['height'] = $thumb_size;            
$this->image_lib->initialize($img);
$this->image_lib->crop();
$this->image_lib->clear();


//watermark image
$img['new_image']    = $destination_thumb ;
$img['wm_overlay_path'] = './images/resource/watermark.png';
$img['wm_type'] = 'overlay';
$img['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'midle';
$img['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'center';
$this->image_lib->initialize($img);
$this->image_lib->watermark();            
$this->image_lib->clear() ;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but no it doesn't work..the result is only watermarking without cropping the image